# How to get all the current partitions of a Delta Table using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I am using the OSS version of delta lake along with spark 3.0.1. My current use-case requires me to discover all the current partitions in a given delta table.

My data is stored in `'./data/raw'` and is partitioned by the column `sensorId` (the path mentioned is relative path to my python script).

I am trying to use the `SHOW PARTITIONS` syntax as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-partitions.html). However, I am getting errors.

This is how my code looks like:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("TestScript").getOrCreate()
df=spark.sql("SHOW PARTITIONS delta.`./data/raw`")
df.show()
```

The spark-submit command looks as follows:

```bash
spark-submit --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0 \
  --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
  --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog" \
  test_script.py
```

And I get the following error:

`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Database 'delta' not found;`

My other question related to this is whether `SHOW PARTITIONS` will give me all the partitions or does it put a limit on the result. If there is a limit, what is the best way to discover/get all the partitions of a delta table.

Comment: Are u using Databricks? Is table saved as delta table? The path that you are giving is the path where the physical parquet files are saved for the delta table?

Comment: the question is about OSS Delta, not Databricks's one...

Comment: @AlexOtt Should I remove the tag? I thought since delta is developed by Databricks, I can reach relevant audience.

Answer (score 2):

You could see the partitions in couple of ways. The link of the documentation that you have given shows you the ways for doing it.

1. If you have save your data as a delta table, you can get the partitions information by providing the table name instead of the delta path and it would return you the partitions information.

   **spark.sql("SHOW Partitions schema.tableName").show()**
2. You can also use the option where you specify the path where the physical files for the table lives. In your case your are passing the relative path based on where your python script is present but that would not work. You need to pass the exact path of the S3 bucket or any storage you are using for it to work.

   **spark.sql("SHOW Partitions delta.`dbfs:/mnt/S3/tables/data/raw` ").show()**

To answer your last question whether Show partitions will give you all the partitions. The answer is yes but if you check that using df.show() if will show you only the first 20 rows.

If you want to see all the rows/partitions for the table you can do count on the dataframe and then pass that as a second parameter to the show method.

```
val count = df.count()
df.show(count, truncate = False)
```

Comment: Tried with the absolute path along with the `dbfs` prefix, but still getting the same error. I am not sure if this solution will work as I am not using delta in a databricks environment.
Also, I would prefer the location path based solution as our code will be running in a k8 env and the data will be in a persistent volume which will be mounted to a particular location.

Comment: using absolute path based on your solution won't work even if you prefixed that with dbfs. You need to use delta in databricks environment for this to work. if your data is in S3 bucket then you can mount your S3 bucket path to databricks and use it as I have shown in the answer. You would be able to get that path from K8 env because it would be in S3.

Comment: We are not using cloud components in our solution. It is will be a local fs or nfs mount. So based on your comments, I understand that OSS delta outside databricks environment can't support the above functionality. Is that right?

Comment: I don't know if such thing is present in OSS delta as I have not tried.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to using SQL: "SHOW PARTITIONS", you can use `DeltaTable` `detail` method (available from version 2.1):

```
from delta.tables import *

# Get partition column names
detailDF = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, deltaPath).detail()
partitionCols = detailDF.select("partitionColumns").collect()[0][0]

# Get values from partition columns
df = spark.read.format("delta").load(deltaPath)
partitionsDF = df.select(partitionCols).distinct()
```

Where `deltaPath` is the location of your delta table, for example in s3 or dbfs.

[See official delta docs for more info](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/python/index.html#delta.tables.DeltaTable.detail)

Comment: partitionsDF = df.select(partitionCols).distinct()

this scans all the files, at least on 2.0.0 (but i don't think you'll ever get to fetch all the partition values in the manner because it's simply what spark does